# Cloudfoundry : Cannot push NodeJS app to Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to push Kibana

https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

to Bluemix PaaS via cloudfoundry. At cf push i get this error

```
Error uploading application.
GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\asd\qwe\zxc\installedPlugins\shield\node_modules\eslint\node_modules\file-entry-cache\node_modules\flat-cache\node_modules\del\node_modules\globby\node_modules\glob\node_modules\inflight\node_modules\wrappy\package.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

i can see that the package.json is actually present at that path! How do i resolve this?

```
cf --version
cf version 6.12.4-b4b6af1-2015-09-18T10:55:12+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the file path being too long. Add the node_modules directory to a .cfignore file in the app's root directory and then push again. The node_modules won't be uploaded and will instead be installed as part of the staging process.

See https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/nodejs-cloudant/blob/master/.cfignore for an example .cfignore.

You could also switch to npm v3 which keeps the node_modules directory flatter, but you still wouldn't normally push it with your app.

Comment: so i create a file named .cfignore that has just one line. node_modules

Comment: i added the file but istill get the error. do i have to do a cf logout first?

Comment: also looked at this

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/29227/why-is-cf-push-choking-on-a-file-thats-in-cfignore.html

Comment: but the file i create is in utf-8. i configured that in notepad++

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date cf CLI?

Comment: hmm, i got this a few months ago. i'll download and install the latest anyway

Comment: i installed the latest version but i still get the same error. why is the .cfignore being ignored?

Comment: Searching around it looks like others have the same problem, I'm not sure what's going on. I also edited my answer to include another idea - try switching to npm v3.